# Summation of gcd of pairs

Tags: summation, gcd-and-lcm

I want to find the mathematical formula for this pseudo-code

ans = 0

for(i = 1 to x)

{

```
for(j = 1 to y)

      ans+= gcd(i, j)
```

}

print ans

Please help me find the formula with a valid proof for it.

Comment: Is it homework ?

Comment: nope. just learning number theory these days. random doubt.